How do I edit Azure Blob Metadata used in Live Service?
To remedy an issue, I've been trying to run a tool to upload new EventHub checkpoint offsets to store in blob metadata. I've also tried manually updating these in the Azure Portal. However, this is not updating the metadata and only seemed to work before my service was live.
Now that I am having an issue with my service, it seems I cannot update offsets ad-hoc.
Is this intentional? It seems like giving preference to admin operations on Azure Portal makes more sense here.

For updating metadata, you typically need the Storage Blob Data Contributor role.

The offset of the event when it was received from the associated Event Hub partition.This value is read-only and will only be populated for events that have been read from Event Hubs. The default value when not populated is null.This property is only populated for events received from the Event Hubs service. If this EventData was not received from the Event Hubs service, the value is MinValue.

There's nothing special about a checkpoint blob - its just an empty file with metadata attributes set.  Any standard Storage client can read/write them.  There's an illustration of writing raw checkpoint data in the Event Hubs migration guide here:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/MigrationGuide.md#migrating-eventprocessorhost-checkpoints.   Rather than reading the legacy checkpoint data, you would just inject the offset + sequence number that you wanted to set.

You are unable to overwrite offsets/sequence numbers manually while your service is live and concurrently updating offsets/sequence numbers.
The reason I was able to update these in the Azure Blobs earlier was because my service was not live yet and so I was not data-racing production checkpointing.
